# Is this sufficient to prove that the positive rational number is countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, summation

n∈N-{0} , m∈N , n/m

f(n,1)=1(n/1) is bijetive and countable...the cardinality is n

f(n,2)=2(n/2) is ibjetive and countable...the cardinality of f(n,2) plus the previous cardinality is 2n-floor(n/2)

f(n,3)=3(n/3) is ibjetive and countable...the cardinality of f(n,3) plus the previous cardinality is 3n-floor(n/3)

.

.

.

The cardinality of f(n,m) is nm+1-$\sum_{i=2}^{m} $$⌊\frac{n}{i}⌋$ and it is countable.

+1 because of 0/m

My question is :

1.Did it prove postive rational number is countable?

2.How to change $\sum_{i=2}^{m} $$-⌊\frac{n}{i}⌋$ to the closed form?

Comment: The argument is correct. There should be a concrete bijection somewhere on this site.

Comment: @Peter Such a concrete bijection is given, for example, by the [Calkin-Wilf sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree). A proof that such a sequence enumerates the positive rationals can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641364/proving-that-the-calkin-wilf-tree-enumerates-the-rationals).